# Posting and redirecting to another page don't save data

Tags: redirect

I am new to PHP-HTML

My current page is register.php. after user fills all registration forms I submit an INSERT query and it saves when action is to the same page:

```
<form method="POST" action="register.php"" enctype="multipart/form-data">  //works
```

Redirecting the page changes to the other page but fails to store data:

```
<form method="POST" action="directorioimagenes.php"" enctype="multipart/form-data">  //don't work
```

this is my button , maybe that's the problem?:

```
<div>
    <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
</div>
```